# CollectionView delegate and dataSource outlet ignored in interface builder, but works when hardcoded. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a tableviewcell in the form a xib, that contains a collection view. When I set the outlet from the collectionview to the Files owner and set the delegate and datasource, both the delegate methods and datasource methods are not called.

However, if I call a setup method after the tableviewcell is created and hardcode them like the following:

```
  func setupCell() {
      collectionView.delegate = self
      collectionView.dataSource = self
  }
```

the delegate methods and datasource methods are called and everything works.

Is there a way to set up the delegate and datasource in interface builder without hardcoding them?

Comment: Did you set view to conform to `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate`

Comment: I have my tableViewCell it conforming to `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and `UICollectionViewDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your table view cell will get dequeued after storyboard sets the delegates. So the delegate from storyboard never really gets set when the cell gets loaded.

You will have to set them programmatically when you setup the cell (like you already found out)

```
 func setupCell() {
      collectionView.delegate = self
      collectionView.dataSource = self
  }
```